How to Calculate Focal Length when in another medium?
How do you calculate the focal length of a lens when it is placed into another medium, if I only have the focal length of a lens in the air? I understand that the lensmaker's equation should be used, but I'm not sure how it works.

This might help - Lensmaker's equation for thick lens in two different media
